# Eclipse error during adding new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, adt

I can't add new activity into my project.
At the end of the "add activity" wizard, if I click on the finish button the wizard is still opened and only the manifest file is changed.

I am using Android Developer Tools Build: v22.0.0-675183

**Error from eclipse (android\.metadata\.log)**

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-06-02 14:46:09.807
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard.performFinish(TemplateWizard.java:164)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard$1.run(TemplateWizard.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: End position lies outside document range
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.Changes.asCoreException(Changes.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.perform(TextChange.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard.performFinish(TemplateWizard.java:161)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.text.edits.MalformedTreeException: End position lies outside document range
    at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditProcessor.checkIntegrityDo(TextEditProcessor.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit.dispatchCheckIntegrity(TextEdit.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditProcessor.performEdits(TextEditProcessor.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.performEdits(TextChange.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextFileChange.performEdits(TextFileChange.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.perform(TextChange.java:238)
    ... 4 more
Root exception:
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: End position lies outside document range
            at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.Changes.asCoreException(Changes.java:62)
            at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.perform(TextChange.java:246)
            at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
            at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard.performFinish(TemplateWizard.java:161)
            at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard$1.run(TemplateWizard.java:188)
            at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
        Caused by: org.eclipse.text.edits.MalformedTreeException: End position lies outside document range
            at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditProcessor.checkIntegrityDo(TextEditProcessor.java:178)
            at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit.dispatchCheckIntegrity(TextEdit.java:743)
            at org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditProcessor.performEdits(TextEditProcessor.java:151)
            at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.performEdits(TextChange.java:277)
            at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextFileChange.performEdits(TextFileChange.java:262)
            at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.TextChange.perform(TextChange.java:238)
            ... 4 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try re-starting eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, but with no change.

Comment: Is this your 1st Android project? Have you installed Android SDK Build-tools using the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: yes i have. Everything works fine on the other projects. I have closed all unused project but error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when adding a new activity.

Starting eclipse with the `-clean`-command had no effect, so i tried to convert the XML files with Notepad++ from **UTF-8** to **UTF8 without BOM**. This worked for me. I did this for every XML file, so the manifest, `layout.xml` , `dimens.xml` and `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same effect. The solution was the file 'strings.xml', which had a wrong character encoding (something else than UTF-8 - I’ve edited 'strings.xml' with an editor outside of Eclipse, which saved it in the wrong encoding).

Using a backup of 'strings.xml' (which was still UTF-8 encoded) and doing the editing in Eclipse, did solve the problem.

I found the wrong file by clicking on it in the Activity-Wizards Preview under 'Changes to be performed'.